# How to schedule jobs to run once per month on Databricks?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, databricks

I want to create an automated data pipeline but I have access to only Databricks. Is it possible to have Datbricks run automatically once per month? I have the jobs set up but I need them to run automatically.

Is it possible? I Googled and didnt find a direct way to do this.

Googled "Schedule jobs on Databricks", "Automate databricks by timed schedule", "Automating databricks"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, here is the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/jobs/jobs.html#job-schedule). Databricks supports the Quartz Cron Syntax.

Comment: Thank you. And if I have multiple data sources -- is there a way to process them one at a time?